# how can I pass my dropdown value to CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter and want to get value from my View's `new.php` dropdown which has entries from an existing database to my controller `Newhome.php`.

My view's HTML code goes like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo base_url("index.php/Newhome/download");?>" method="post"  id="createFrm" name="createFrm" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">STATE</label>
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select a state</option>
                        <?php 
                        if(!empty($states)) {
                            foreach ($states as $states) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $states['state_id'];?>"><?php echo $states['state_name'];?></option>}
                                <?php
                            }
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <p class="state_error"></p>
                     
                </div>
            

            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Newhome/download')?>" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Download</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

My Newhome controller's download function goes like this:

```
public function download(){
    $arrData= $this->input->post('state');
    
    print_r ($arrData);
```

But I am unable to get any value here in the print_r() function, please suggest some way to do it

Thank you for any contribution in advance.

Comment: you need to submit the form to get the value

Comment: Yes i have a button doing it! But not reflected here

Comment: Share your complete view code

Comment: @mail2bapi I have edited and added full view code

Comment: `<a>` tag cannot submit form use `<button>` tag

Comment: @kp singh your problem is solved or not??

Comment: @KUMAR yes the answer posted by Vinie works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<button>` instead of `<a>` tag. `<a>` tag don't have type property.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo base_url("index.php/Newhome/download");?>" method="post"  id="createFrm" name="createFrm" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">STATE</label>
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select a state</option>
                        <?php 
                        if(!empty($states)) {
                            foreach ($states as $states) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $states['state_id'];?>"><?php echo $states['state_name'];?></option>}
                                <?php
                            }
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <p class="state_error"></p>
                     
                </div>
            

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Download</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this helps you please mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move this `onchange="this.form.submit()"` from the `form` tag to the `select`:

```
<select name="state" id="state" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```